# r - How to compute sum of 'sublevels' in nested list

Tags: r, nested-lists

I have a nested list `mylist`. In the first 'level' of `mylist` there are four vegetation types. In the second 'level', I have a measurement of water stress for 15 soil levels (named `level1`, `level2` and so on until `level15`).

This is my dataset:

```
mylist <- structure(list(needleleaf_evergreen_temperate_tree = structure(list(
    layer1 = 0.074844339399475, layer2 = 0.10364235153792, layer3 = 0.139199261740378, 
    layer4 = 0.16641474105245, layer5 = 0.169465314138987, layer6 = 0.144044051642624, 
    layer7 = 0.105600767636715, layer8 = 0.0652887370818433, 
    layer9 = 0.0264351101290891, layer10 = 0.00481604897579532, 
    layer11 = 0.000247537572307209, layer12 = 1.73860803440901e-06, 
    layer13 = 4.8438137437183e-10, layer14 = 6.6619638078275e-16, 
    layer15 = 2.88818224958405e-25), .Names = c("layer1", "layer2", 
"layer3", "layer4", "layer5", "layer6", "layer7", "layer8", "layer9", 
"layer10", "layer11", "layer12", "layer13", "layer14", "layer15"
)), needleleaf_evergreen_boreal_tree = structure(list(layer1 = 0.074844339399475, 
    layer2 = 0.10364235153792, layer3 = 0.139199261740378, layer4 = 0.16641474105245, 
    layer5 = 0.169465314138987, layer6 = 0.144044051642624, layer7 = 0.105600767636715, 
    layer8 = 0.0652887370818433, layer9 = 0.0264351101290891, 
    layer10 = 0.00481604897579532, layer11 = 0.000247537572307209, 
    layer12 = 1.73860803440901e-06, layer13 = 4.8438137437183e-10, 
    layer14 = 6.6619638078275e-16, layer15 = 2.88818224958405e-25), .Names = c("layer1", 
"layer2", "layer3", "layer4", "layer5", "layer6", "layer7", "layer8", 
"layer9", "layer10", "layer11", "layer12", "layer13", "layer14", 
"layer15")), needleleaf_deciduous_boreal_tree = structure(list(
    layer1 = 0.074844339399475, layer2 = 0.10364235153792, layer3 = 0.139199261740378, 
    layer4 = 0.16641474105245, layer5 = 0.169465314138987, layer6 = 0.144044051642624, 
    layer7 = 0.105600767636715, layer8 = 0.0652887370818433, 
    layer9 = 0.0264351101290891, layer10 = 0.00481604897579532, 
    layer11 = 0.000247537572307209, layer12 = 1.73860803440901e-06, 
    layer13 = 4.8438137437183e-10, layer14 = 6.6619638078275e-16, 
    layer15 = 2.88818224958405e-25), .Names = c("layer1", "layer2", 
"layer3", "layer4", "layer5", "layer6", "layer7", "layer8", "layer9", 
"layer10", "layer11", "layer12", "layer13", "layer14", "layer15"
)), c3_irrigated = structure(list(layer1 = 0.0754105781789665, 
    layer2 = 0.106401701696586, layer3 = 0.146857331360997, layer4 = 0.181972345543274, 
    layer5 = 0.191196461077081, layer6 = 0.158267532821584, layer7 = 0.094842247909502, 
    layer8 = 0.0370323148644247, layer9 = 0.00750914382571778, 
    layer10 = 0.000504776733855199, layer11 = 5.5627446227042e-06, 
    layer12 = 3.24337357358994e-09, layer13 = 1.50763789751944e-14, 
    layer14 = 2.43174707104567e-23, layer15 = 1.55216144591354e-37), .Names = c("layer1", 
"layer2", "layer3", "layer4", "layer5", "layer6", "layer7", "layer8", 
"layer9", "layer10", "layer11", "layer12", "layer13", "layer14", 
"layer15"))), .Names = c("needleleaf_evergreen_temperate_tree", 
"needleleaf_evergreen_boreal_tree", "needleleaf_deciduous_boreal_tree", 
"c3_irrigated"))
```

What I need to do is to sum water stress over the 15 soil levels, for each vegetation type (i.e. sum all 'sublevels' for each 'level' of the list).

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: `newlist <- lapply(mylist, function(x) sum(unlist(x)))`?

Comment: Thanks @Parfait, it works! Can you please write it as an answer, so I am able to accept it?

Comment: you can also use `colSums(unstack(stack(mylist)))` or `Map(Reduce,"+",mylist)` although this does not keep the names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call `lapply` and because nested content are in lists, run `unlist` to convert sublist items to numeric vectors for the `sum`:

```
newlist <- lapply(mylist, function(x) sum(unlist(x)))
```